# How to apply overlapping pragma to derived instance

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, overlapping-instances

Pragma OverlappingInstances is deprecated in GHC for quite awhile and
OVERLAPPING pragma is a substitute for that.

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #- } ...
```

Though this is not the only way in Haskell to define a class instance.
I cannot define overlapping instance through deriving and avoid pesky warning about deprecated OverlappingInstances.

None of below cases are working:

```
  deriving {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Lift)
  deriving ({-# OVERLAPPING #-} Lift)
```

Comment: Of course, my real opinion about overlapping instances is "don't do that", but I know others see it differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `StandaloneDeriving` for such instances, as well as for ones that need specialized instance contexts.

```hs
{-# language StandaloneDeriving, FlexibleInstances #-}

data T a = T

deriving instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Show (T Int)
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Show (T a) where
  show ~T = "Tee-hee"

main = do
  print (T :: T Int)
  print (T :: T Char)
```